# Find : $(a^{2^m}+1,a^{2^n}+1)$ and hence prove infinitude of prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find $(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)$ and prove that there are infinitely many primes.

My Attempt:

Since $x+1|x^{2k}-1$

$\implies [(a)^{2^m}+1]|[(a^{2^m})^{2^{n-m}}-1]$.

How to proceed?

Comment: I do not understand your question, it is not clear, please consider improving it...
Use math mode: \$ (equation) \$

Comment: use curly braces for your exponent. $2^{3+x}$ is typed as 2^{3+x}. Also, the question is very vague to me

Comment: i am trying but its not really happening

Comment: Quite clear, I even have an answer. Question got closed while I was typing, voting for reopening

Answer (score 1):

Divide question in two parts:

$1.$ $(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)$

$2.$ Prove infinitude of prime using $1$.

For first part:

Note that $x+1|x^{2k}-1$ for a positive integer $k$. WLOG assume that $m<n$ and put $x=a^{2^m}$ and $k=2^{n-m}$. Hence $a^{2^m}|(a^{2^m})^{2^{n-m}}-1$.

We get $(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)=$ $1$ if $a$ is even and $2$ if $a$ is odd.

For second part:

Now assume $a$ to be any even number (like $2$). Thus using $1$ we know that $(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)=1$ which implies $(a^{2^m}+1$ and $a^{2^n}+1)$ share no factor other than $1$. If $p_m$ denotes prime dividing $a^{2^m}+1$ and $p_n$  denotes prime dividing $a^{2^{n}}+1$ then $(p_m,p_n)=1$ whenever $m\ne n$ hence there are infinitely many primes.